# What APIs are available to access a camera in HTML5

Tags: html, camera, webkit, qtwebkit, getusermedia

I am looking for APIs for accessing a camera on a device using HTML. I am aware of `getUserMedia()`, but that appears to only be supported by the Blink and Gecko engines. Is there anything else out there? I am specifically looking for something that WebKit/QtWebKit supports.

Comment: Take a look at this, Using webkitGetUserMedia. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 2015-09-23:** I’ve been told be a WebKit browser engineer that WebKit doesn’t support `getUserMedia`—not even prefixed as `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`. I’m not sure if it did at one point and the support was removed, or what.

So I think the answer as far as being able to get something working with Safari is, It's not possible.

As far as recent changes in support in other browsers, though, it seems that unprefixed `navigator.getUserMedia()` [is now supported in Edge](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/mediacaptureandstreams/).

Comment: I'm confused by the existence of navigator.webkitGetUserMedia because it doesn't seem to work. The examples in the following tutoriols `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/` use the same conditional setting of navigator.geUserMedia that you do, but Safari still says, "getUserMedia() not supported in your browser." So there is a WebKit API for getUserMedia, but it doesn't work?

Comment: Ah yeah, I do get an error that “not supported” error in Safari 8 but not in WebKit nightly. Instead in WebKit I get a “permission denied” and I’m now trying to remember how to get the permissions prompt to show up in Safari as expected…

Comment: Update: A WebKit engineer has told me that Safari definitely does not support `getUserMedia`—even prefixed. Sorry for having added to the confusion. I’ll revise my answer.

Comment: No problem, sideshowbarker. I appreciate the responsiveness. I am currently cloning the WebKit repository to try running in that. If you don't mind me asking, and forgive my ignorance, but I was not aware WebKit could be run standalone? Does it have a browser interface built in? I am specifically looking to support getUserMedia from within a Qt application on an i.MX6 board. So if the latest WebKit supports it, I may be able to integrate it into my Qt build (replacing whatever version of WebKit that comes with Qt5.4.2)

Comment: Also, regarding your edit, you stated that the engineer said "WebKit" doesn't support getUserMedia. Did you mean Safari? Didn't getUserMedia work in the WebKit nightly build?

Comment: Yeah, so there are nightly builds of "WebKit" the browser at http://nightly.webkit.org/ which are a build of WebKit the engine from the latest tip-of-tree sources in the WebKit repo and essentially just run the Safari browser UI but cause it to link to that WebKit-the-engine build rather than the stable/release engine that Safari would normally run.

Comment: Anyway, I took the meaning of the WebKit engineer I talked with to be that getUserMedia isn’t supported in WebKit-the-engine, rather the just not being supported in Safari. In which case, that means it won’t work in Qt either. But the part of the implementation code for interacting with the camera & mic is platform-level code rather than just core browser-engine, & because it varies by platform, I suppose there may be some possibility  Qt implements platform code for it while Safari doesn't．But as far as I can see that doesn't seem to be the case. It doesn't work with any WebKit-based browsers

Comment: I talked to a guy on the WebKit IRC earlier today that said the streams API was currently being implemented by some developer. Which may explain why you built the WebKit nightly and it worked. But he also said the port of WebKit for Qt was passed off to Qt ~3 years ago. And Qt has marked is as deprecated. So it looks like that is just a dead end. I have the camera working at a platform level, was interested in accessing it from an HTML5 UI environment. Just doesn't look like that's possible outside of a browser running Blink or Gecko.